# ID attribute selector ^ doesn’t work

Tags: html, css, attributes, css-selectors

I have this code:

```css
#ul_quests {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

[id=^"q_count"],
[id="q_watcher"],
[id=^"q_date"],
[id=^"q_addresses"] {
  height: 55px;
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 35px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_quests">
  <li id='q_count1'>1</li>
  <li id='q_watcher1'>fdsfss</li>
  <li id='q_date1'>20-20</li>
  <li id='q_addresses1'></li>
</ul>
```

But the CSS doesn’t apply to the IDs. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwspvok6/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[id^="q_count"]` is the right way. `[id=^"q_count"]` this is not

```css
#ul_quests{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

[id^="q_count"],[id="q_watcher"],[id^="q_date"],[id^="q_addresses"]{
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 35px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul_quests">
    <li id='q_count1'>1</li>
    <li id='q_watcher1'>fdsfss</li>
    <li id='q_date1'>20-20</li>
    <li id='q_addresses1'></li>
</ul>
```